# When cleanup function of UseEffect triggering clearInterval() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, setinterval, use-effect

I am making a timer in a Tenzie game. When a user clicks a button, onClick function sets the **isTimerActive** state to *true* which was initially *false* and **tenzie** state is also *false* to default and when user complete the game **tenzie** state sets to *true*.

```
     React.useEffect(() => {
      let timer = null;

       if(isTimerActive && !tenzie){
        timer = setInterval(() => {
           setTime(prevSecond => prevSecond + 1);
        }, 1000);
      }
     
       return () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
       }
  }, [tenzie, isTimerActive])
```

I want to know when React runs this cleanup function and if it runs it every time it runs useEffect then why my timer is working ?

Comment: The cleanup function runs every time a dependency changes. Why wouldn’t it work? Are you confusing the order it runs? The cleanup function runs (to.. clean up) and then your use effect runs.  Why don’t you add some logs to see it in action.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita Correct ! By doing some console  logging, I'm able to understand it very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here the simple answer is cleanup function of useEffect runs only when the component gets unmount, it never runs each the useEffect's callback gets executed, it only runs if your component is getting un-mount.

Reff docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect

Its good to have cleanup function for these scenario (as you are using setInterval) because you don't want setInterval to call even after you component gets unmount. So its better to clear the interval in the clean up function before un mounting the component.

Comment: Sorry but cleanup function also get executed just before another call of useEffect function so that it can cleanup the previous call and get execute the new one. You can console.log to see it in action.

Comment: Cleanup function executes every dependency change.